# Make the checkbox on a mult-line JCheckbox align with the first line, not the center

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jcheckbox, grouplayout

I am running a program that adds multiple different JCheckBoxes to a GroupLayout JPanel on a JFrame and I've hit a slight problem.
With the following code the program will successfully make a multi-line JCheckBox, but the checkbox vertically aligns in the center of the 4 lines and I want it to align with the first line:

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.swing.*; 
    import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
    import javax.swing.GroupLayout;

    public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame f = new JFrame("Survey");
            JPanel p = new JPanel();

            GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(p);
            GroupLayout.SequentialGroup hGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();
            GroupLayout.SequentialGroup vGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();

            p.setLayout(layout);

            JCheckBox example = new JCheckBox();
            example.setText("<html><body>lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum");

            hGroup.addComponent(example, 0,150,150);
            vGroup.addComponent(example);

            layout.setHorizontalGroup(hGroup);
            layout.setVerticalGroup(vGroup); 
            f.add(p);
            f.setVisible(true);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setVisible(true);
            f.setExtendedState(f.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        }  
    }
```

Output:

[image: Output]

I want it to look like this (Mind my terrible image editing skills and the fact that its randomly a different shade of grey):

[image: Desired result]

As you can see I use GroupLayout, if possible I would like to retain this because I want to apply this to a much larger program and restructuring my entire layout is less than ideal.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `AbstractButton` API.

There are several methods that allow you to control the location of the text relative to the icon.

For example:

```
JCheckBox example = new JCheckBox();
example.setText("<html><body>lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum");
example.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.TOP);
```

Comment: This works, but it aligns the top of the checkbox with the top of the text.   It would look better if the bottom of the checkbox aligned with the baseline of the first line of text.   But that would probably require creating a customized layout for the JCheckBox.  Not everyone will notice the difference anyway.